# How to enable WIFI on new Ubuntu-Dell Laptop

Tags: linux, dell-inspiron, ubuntu-16.04, wifi-driver, dmesg

I just bought a new dell laptop and installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 on it:

https://www.google.com/search?q=dell+inspiron+17+5000&oq=dell+inspiron+17+5000

When I log in I see this:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Linux d79 4.4.0-127-generic #153-Ubuntu SMP Sat May 19 10:58:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Wifi does not work.

I see a clue here:

```
dan@d79:~ $ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5914 (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5917 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31)
dan@d79:~ $ 
dan@d79:~ $
```

And I see a clue here:

```
dan@d79:~ $ dmesg | grep -i ath
[  174.153964] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  174.154791] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[  175.004439] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[  175.004459] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[  175.004461] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[  175.004465] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -2
[  175.004466] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin': -2
[  175.004470] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2
[  175.004471] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin': -2
[  175.004474] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin failed with error -2
[  175.004476] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin': -2
[  175.004480] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware.bin failed with error -2
[  175.004481] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2)
[  175.004483] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[  175.004484] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
dan@d79:~ $ 
dan@d79:~ $
```

I would welcome any ideas on how to get WIFI working on my Ubuntu-Dell-Laptop.

Comment: Is `linux-firmware` package installed?

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that it wasn't included in the standard Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it:

```
sudo apt install linux-firmware
```

yay!

Comment: Did @Kamil gave you hint (in his comments) for this answer ?

Comment: not seeing the wifi ubuntu 10.04 on a dell latitude E6540 for me